# Concatenate only is if there is an object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe built from a csv file that contains studentID, Name, and Assignment1,2,3... The csv file is to be entered as an input, so the values can vary.

I want to print a list of error messages if the student ID is not unique. The code below works fine because there are no duplicates in gradesM3.csv:

```
        grades = pd.read_csv('gradesM3.csv',sep=';')
        duplicates = pd.concat(g for _, g in grades.groupby("StudentID") if len(g) > 1)      
        zipped = zip(duplicates['StudentID'])
        for student in zipped:
            print(f'The student ID {student} appears multiple times.')
```

However if I change my CSV file and create some duplicate student IDs, then I get the following error:

```
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

I am trying to write a code that prints the following if there are duplicates:

```
The student ID ('s123789',) appears multiple times.

The student ID ('s123789',) appears multiple times.

The student ID ('s123789',) appears multiple times.
```

And the following if there are none:

```
There are no duplicates in your file.
```

I have tried the following code:

```
        grades = pd.read_csv('gradesM3.csv',sep=';')
        duplicates = pd.concat(g for _, g in grades.groupby("StudentID") if len(g) > 1) 
        if len(duplicates)>0:
            zipped = zip(duplicates['StudentID'])
            for student in zipped:
                print(f'The student ID {student} appears multiple times.')
        else:
            print('The grades are correctly scaled along the 7-point grading system.')
```

But I get the same error message:

```
ValueError: No objects to concatenate.
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue there is your error comes from the line:

```
duplicates = pd.concat(g for _, g in grades.groupby("StudentID") if len(g) > 1)
```

Since you manage the empty case after that line, the error still happens. One solution is to use a `try except` syntax :

```
grades = pd.read_csv('gradesM3.csv',sep=';')
try:
    duplicates = pd.concat(g for _, g in grades.groupby("StudentID") if len(g) > 1)
    zipped = zip(duplicates['StudentID'])
    for student in zipped:
        print(f'The student ID {student} appears multiple times.')
except ValueError:
    print('The grades are correctly scaled along the 7-point grading system.')
```

Answer (score 2):

A more direct solution is something like this using the `duplicated` method of pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,2,4, 5, 1], 'name' : ["a", "b", "b", "d", "e", "a"]})
print(df)

#   id name
#0   1    a
#1   2    b
#2   2    b
#3   4    d
#4   5    e
#5   1    a

# Get the duplicates - each df row where th eid column is duplicated
df_duplicates  = df[df['id'].duplicated()]

for id in df_duplicates['id']:
    print(f"Student {id} is a duplicate")


#Student 2 is a duplicate
#Student 1 is a duplicate
```